# Django template optimization

Tags: django, django-templates

With a list of dicts containing a total of over 30,000 values and looks something like

```
[
    {
        "line": "First Item",
        "data": {"2019-01-01": 1234, ..., "2040-01-01": -3123}
    },
    {
        "line": "Second Item",
        "data": {"2018-01-01": 1512, ..., "2037-12-01": -4123}
    },
]
```

and calling 10-15 template tags per value for 300k to 500k template tag calls, my performance in rendering a request has degraded materially.

My template tags do things like get value from `data` given date, format number with specific format string that is distinct per line, format for negative numbers or zeroes, etc.

In an effort to make more readable code and be DRY, I also do a lot of nested template includes, resulting in over 12,000 calls to template rendering.

My choices seem to be to

- Reduce the number of template includes
- Return data easier to parse and requiring fewer template tag calls. This only works up to a point.
- Return formatted data or even html snippets instead of calling template tags as much
- Do something else - and I don't know what something else is

I'm seeking pointers/ways to address the huge performance hit problem I have created for myself.

Comment: What use case do you have for rendering 30,000 elements?

Comment: Using the [cached template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader) might help (it is enabled by default in Django 1.11+ when `DEBUG` is `False`. You might get better performance with a different template engine, e.g. Jinja2.

Comment: @IainShelvington - displaying the inputs and outputs associated with some data modeling with 150 rows and 200 columns of values representing line items and dates respectively.

Comment: @Vishal I would recommend rendering your data in a completely different way. For instance you could return your data set as JSON from an API endpoint and render the content on the page with a javascript framework. While you will still have some issue with performance, the user experience can be made slightly better by not having them wait for the entire html template to be rendered

Comment: That makes sense and I have considered it. I already have an API endpoint for the same data.